# Print fibonacci up to user entered number

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the Fibonacci series up to whatever number the user types in. The problem is that my code ends up printing that amount of numbers. If a user enters 100, I want the code to stop at 100, but my code prints 100 numbers. Also, I'm supposed to have printf and a while statement. I don't even know how to use printf.

```
package l12;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class L12 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");


        int n = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The Fibonacci numbers less than " + n + " are: ");

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            System.out.print(fibonacci(i) +" ");

        }
    }
    public static int fibonacci(int n){
        if(n == 1 || n == 2){
            return 1;
        }
        int f1=1;
        int f2=1;
        int fibonacci=1;


        for(int i= 3; i<= n; i++){



            do {   fibonacci = f1 + f2;
                f1 = f2;
                f2 = fibonacci;

            }

            while (fibonacci <= n);



        }
        return fibonacci;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of doing it would be :

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
    int n = console.nextInt();
    if(n>1) {
        System.out.println("The Fibonacci numbers less than " + n + " are: ");
        System.out.print("1, 1, ");
        int f2=1;
        int fibonacci=1;
        for(int i=1; i+f2 < n;){
            fibonacci = i + f2;
            i = f2;
            f2 = fibonacci;
            System.out.print(fibonacci+", ");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("There are no numbers less than " + n + " in the series");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. much easier way. i'm going to practice this a little more.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you could change this (which stops when `i > n`)

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
  System.out.print(fibonacci(i) +" ");
}
```

to something like this, which stops when the result of `fibonacci(i) > n`, stores the result in `fib` and uses `printf` (the [Format `String` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) says that with `d` *The result is formatted as a decimal integer*).

```
int fib;
for (int i = 1; (fib = fibonacci(i)) <= n; i++) { // <-- stop wehn fib >= n
    System.out.printf("%d ", fib); // <-- printf.
}
System.out.println(); // <-- Add a new-line.
```

Answer (score 1):

I will be giving you an answer in Go so if you watch closely, you'll see the following sequence:

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 ...

The formula for mapping the Fibonacci sequence is:

[image]

Then if you code this (Go):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci() func() int {
    first, second := 0, 1
    return func() int {
        ret := first
        first, second = second, first+second
        return ret
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < /* What users enter */; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

You'll see the numbers till entered by user. I hope that approach helped you understand better the problem!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This prints 100 numbers because you are looping n times no matter what:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    System.out.print(fibonacci(i) +" ");
}
```

I would recommend changing this to a do-while loop as well:

```
int i = 1;
int fib;
do{
   fib = fibonacci(i);
   System.out.print(fib + " ");
} while(fib < n);
```

The above code, as I hinted at, is always going to loop 100 times. Even though your fibonacci method doesn't let it exceed 100, your for loop is still going to print 100 numbers.