# Fibonacci series number checking(Check if a user input number is a fibonacci number)

Tags: java, fibonacci

How can I ask the user to input any number using `Scanner`,and then show them if the number they have entered is a *fibonacci* number or not.

```
int[] ar = new int[200];
System.out.print(0+" "+1+" ");
for (int i = 2; i < 110; i++) {
    ar[0] = 0;
    ar[1] = 1;
    ar[i] = ar[i-2] + ar[i-1];
    System.out.print(ar[i]+" ");
}
//The code above prints out some fibonacci numbers

System.out.println(Type in a number: );
int x = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: you want to take complete i/p from user then check or while taking i/p itself you want to check for fibonacci?

Comment: You could save your fibonacci numbers in a ```Set``` and when user gives an input, see if it's in your set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print fibonacci up to user entered number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937602/print-fibonacci-up-to-user-entered-number)

Comment: what have you done so far except showing some numbers of the series? At which step do you have struggles?

Comment: Ekrem ,if the user enters a number that is not in the list I wont to tell them "Your number is not a fibonacci number".

Comment: In the generic case: If the array is sorted (which it is), this test will work: `Arrays.binarySearch(ar, 0, 110, x) >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below snippet. Replace the `for` generated values with your input from the user.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i ++) {
        System.out.println("Is " + i + " fibonacci: " + isFibonacci(i));
    }
}

public static boolean isFibonacci(int x) {
    return isPerfectSquare(5*x*x + 4) || isPerfectSquare(5*x*x - 4);
}

public static boolean isPerfectSquare(double x) {
    double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(x);
    return ((squareRoot - Math.floor(squareRoot)) == 0);
}
```

For the math behind it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not/10002#10002

Comment: Thank you very much.That is pure genius, I would've never thought of it.